# Biochemistry vs. Molecular Cell Biology

Tags: synonyms

What is the difference between Biochemistry vs. Molecular Cell Biology?  Is the former from chemists who became interested in biology and the later from biologists who became interested in chemistry?  Why can't we all just get along...

Comment: Taxonomy! It's less to do with grammar than with the genealogy of a domain.

Comment: Try an encyclopaedia or [BiologySE](http://biology.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What is the difference between the English language vs. scientific jargon?  Is the former from linguists who became interested in science and the latter from scientists who became interested in linguistics?  Why can't we all just stop asking questions that don't belong on this forum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, biochemistry is a wider term.

Molecular Cell Biology is defined as

> A branch of the biological sciences which deals with the structure,
>   behavior, growth, and reproduction of cells and the function and
>   chemistry of cell components.<sup>[source](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/cell+and+molecular+biologyhttp://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/cell+and+molecular+biology)</sup>

Biochemistry, on the other hand, is described like this:

> Biochemistry, sometimes called biological chemistry, is the study of
>   chemical processes in living organisms, including, but not limited to,
>   living matter. The laws of biochemistry govern all living organisms
>   and living processes.<sup>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemistry)</sup>

On the same wiki article you can also find this:

> Much of biochemistry deals with the structures, functions and
>   interactions of cellular components <...> Other areas of biochemistry
>   include the genetic code (DNA, RNA), protein synthesis, cell membrane
>   transport and signal transduction.

So basically, biochemistry is a wider term which covers not only molecular cell biology, but other fields; molecular cell biology is a smaller branch of science that deals with a more narrow range of problems.